# How to continue loop in Map( /Reduce ) function?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I have a Map function in MongoDB which I'm later using Reduce on. I use a collection which has  a bunch of users in it and users own some channels. However, there are users that do not have any channels and the Map/Reduce function raises an error in my script.

```
     map = Code("function () {"
                "  if(!this.channels) continue;"
                "  this.channels.forEach(function(z) {"
                "       emit(z, 1);"
                "   });"
                "}")
```

When I use return instead of continue to quit the function it works flawlessly except that I don't want to end the loop. Is there any smart way around this?

Thanks for your advice and better widsom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you `return` from `map`, it returns only from `map` for this document. Maps for other documents will be executed regardless of that.

I suggest rewriting your `map` to this form

```
function () {
  if(this.channels) {
    this.channels.forEach(function(z) {
       emit(z, 1);
    });
  }
}
```

I think, this form is more clear. It will emit something for users that have channels, and skip those that don't have any.